# Weird bit values from MySQL table

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, jtable, bit

Having inserted a MySQL table values to a `JTable` and previewing this `JTable`, I noticed that the "BIT" column is returning a "1" as a strange box which I am unable to paste into here, and it returns 0's as blanks. I'll leave a screenshot
of the bit error display:

[image]

Comment: Could be a encoding/collation issue

Answer (score 1):

BIT columns store bits as binary data, not as "1" or "0" (string with the character 1 or 0), you need to convert the bit value to string using [export_set() function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_export-set). If your field is defined as BIT(M) (M is the length of the bit field), then

```
select export_set(field_name, '1','0','',M) from yourtable
```

query will return the bit field's value in a string representation, with continuous 1s and 0s.

Comment: The issue with this would be that I am allowing the user to look at multiple tables. The field name of the column with the BIT values in may change throughout different tables, so I would have to change field name each time.

Answer (score 1):

By [default](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender), `JTable` renders `TableModel` values of type `Boolean` using a `JCheckBox`. You can make the cell editable by returning `true` for that column in your model's implementation of `isCellEditable()`, as shown [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data).

Alternatively, you can

- Return your preferred type for that column in your model's implementation of `getColumnClass()`, as shown [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data).
- Use a custom renderer, as shown [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#renderer).

Comment: Boolean and bit data types are not the same in MySQL. Boolean is just an alias for tinyint, whereas bit data type represents a bit field.

Comment: @Shadow: I defer to you on this; I suspect that the author is using some sort of table model adapter that elicits the default renderer in the manner illustrated.

Comment: What I've actually got at the moment is a piece of code that loops through the rows and columns in the JTable, and if the variable holding the data is equal to the box, it changes it into a 1. I was going to do the same with the 0's, however I don't know what character is used for this (As it's just a blank space, and trying to change a space doesn't work)

Comment: Can you determine if you're seeing a [`WHITE SQUARE`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/25a1/index.htm) or a `JCheckBox`?